# staticMetaObject custom Widget

Tags: qt

Я добавил QChartView в Qt Designer как кастомный виджет (через преобразовать в...). При попытке получить название объекта и имя класса таким образом:

```
qDebug()<<ui->ChartViewAlpha->objectName();
qDebug()<<ui->ChartViewAlpha->staticMetaObject.className();
```

Я получаю корректную информацию. Но,когда я перехватываю какой-нибудь event и пытаюсь получить ту же информацию об этом кастомном виджете, получая его как виджет находящийся под курсором, мне возвращаются пустые строки:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* pe)
{
    qDebug()<<qApp->widgetAt(QCursor::pos())->objectName();// возвращает "", хотя под курсоров кастомный QChartView
    qDebug()<<qApp->widgetAt(QCursor::pos())->staticMetaObject.className();
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Попытка преобразовать через dynamic_cast или qobject_cast к QChartView* возвращает пустой указатель.

Что касается того, что, возможно, там другой объект:

```
    qDebug()<<ui->ChartViewAlpha->objectName();// "ChartViewAlpha"
    qDebug()<<ui->ChartViewAlpha->staticMetaObject.className();// QtCharts::QChartView
    qDebug()<<childAt(ui->ChartViewAlpha->pos());//QWidget(0x0)
    qDebug()<<childAt(ui->ChartViewAlpha->pos())->staticMetaObject.className();//QWidget
```

Comment: возможно, там другой объект.

Comment: @KoVadim , обновил

Comment: мой ответ не поменялся. Поверх Вашего объекта может быть другой объект. А если QChartView  добавить по нормальному, то все работает как нужно?

Comment: @KoVadim , по нормальному, в смысле, в ручную? да, так нормально